# C++ std::unique_ptr return from function and test for null

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a function that needs to return a pointer to an object of class `myClass`. For this purpose I´m using `std::unique_ptr`.

If the function succeeds, it shall return a pointer to a object with data. If it fails, it should return `null`.

This is my code skeleton:

```
std::unique_ptr<myClass> getData()
{
   if (dataExists)
      ... create a new myClass object, populate and return it ...

   // No data found
   return std::unique_ptr<myClass> (null); // <--- Possible?
}
```

on `main`:

```
main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<myClass> returnedData;

   returnedData = getData();

   if (returnedData != null)  // <-- How to test for null?
   {
      cout << "No data returned." << endl;
      return 0;
   }

   // Process data
}
```

So here goes my questions:

a) Is that (returning an object or `null`) possible to be done using `std::unique_ptr`?

b) If possible, how to implement is?

c) If not possible, what are there alternatives?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Creating a unique pointer as `std::unique_ptr<T> myptr;` doesn't allocate any memory, so you don't need to construct it and pass `nullptr` at all. So you can just create one and return it.

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword new in C++11 for better support of null pointers. `unique_ptr` can be constructed from `nullptr`, even implicitly.

Comment: I see the != operator is being deprecated in C++20 for `unique_ptr`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: @wcochran the definition of the operator != has been removed in C++20, but thanks to the spaceship operator <=> you can still use the != on the type (and all other comparisons).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Either of the following should work:

```
return std::unique_ptr<myClass>{};
return std::unique_ptr<myClass>(nullptr);
```

To test whether the returned object points to a valid object or not, simply use:

```
if ( returnedData )
{
   // ...
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool.

Comment: Testing the result will be like `if (returnedData != std::nullptr)` ?

Comment: @Mendes: yes. `unique_ptr` has a conversion to `bool` operator that indicates whether the unique pointer is empty or not.

Answer (score 12):

Yes it's possible. A default constructed [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) is what you want:

> Constructs a `std::unique_ptr` that owns nothing.

```
// No data found
return std::unique_ptr<myClass>{};
```

That is equivalent to the `nullptr_t` constructor, so perhaps this is more clear:

```
// No data found
return nullptr;
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes,  it is possible. A default constructed `unique_ptr` or one constructed from `nullptr` can be considered null:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> getData()
{
    if (dataExists)
        return std::make_unique<MyClass>();
    return nullptr;
}
```

To test for null either compare against `nullptr` or take advantage of conversion to bool:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> returnedData = getData();

    if (returnedData)
    {
        ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the latest C++ library there should be a `make_unique` function in `<memory>` allowing us to make `unique_ptr`'s as easily as in the C++11 library allows with `make_shared` and shared pointers.

So you could elucidate the code a little by returning `std::make_unique(nullptr)`

Plus in the next version of C++ there will be an "option" type which will evaluate as either a `some` value or a `none` value. The `none` value won't be allowed to be treated as if it was a valid value, unlike the empty unique_ptr could be treated like a nullptr. The option type will represent yet another piece of Boost entering the standard library.

Comment: Yup, `boost::optional`. Is there a document showing its acceptance into C++17? Edit: I guess this'll do: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: @underscore_d At [this](https://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/c17-library-papers-for-cologne.html) the N paper appears to be N4270, although the actual linked version of the paper seems rough (or "drafty" shall we say?)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info! I hadn't heard about this being incorporated until now... or if I did hear, then I immediately forgot.

Comment: Your suggested code is wrong; `std::make_unique` requires a template argument specifying the object type to create, it forwards the function arguments to *that object's constructor*, and it never returns an empty pointer. Creating an empty pointer is just `std::unique_ptr<myClass>{}`; creating non-empty is `std::make_unique<myClass>(myClassCtorArgs...)`